# Django channels 2 ошибка при использовании get_channel_layer() - возвращает None

Tags: python-3.x, django-channels

Помогите понять, что я делаю не так.

Приложение состоит из 3-х частей. 1)Вебсокет-сервер, который отсылает данные. 2)Вебсокет-клиент, которые принимает эти данные и обрабатывает. В случае получения определенных данных выдает сообщение в лог. 3)Собственно django и django-channels - в случае сообщения в лог, должно отправляться сообщение через django-channels с информацией про такое событие на HTML-страницу. Для отправки такого сообщения, через djang0-channels, использую функцию `channel_layer = get_channel_layer()`. Функция возвращает **None** и поэтому я не могу использовать метод `channel_layer.send()`, что бы отправить сообщение.

### Код

В **settings.py** настройка channel layer

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Я использую redis на windows 7 и redis есть в PATH. Когда ввожу в cmd: redis-cli ping получаю PONG в ответ. Вроде как редис-сервер работает.

**ws_server.py**

```
from numpy import random as npr
import asyncio
import websockets

mu, sigma = 0.5, 0.1


async def send_number(websocket, path):
    sequence_number = 1
    while True:
        sended_number = npr.normal(mu, sigma)
        await websocket.send("{},{},{},{}".format(sended_number, sequence_number, mu, sigma))
        sequence_number += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

start_server = websockets.serve(send_number, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**ws_client.py**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from datetime import datetime
import logging

from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from django_softconstruct.websocket_message.consumers import MessageConsumer


from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(DEBUG=True)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger_ws_client = logging.getLogger('ws_client')


async def recv_hand_message():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        while True:
            number_seqnuber = await websocket.recv()
            number = float(number_seqnuber.split(',')[0])
            sequence_number = int(number_seqnuber.split(',')[1])
            mu = float(number_seqnuber.split(',')[2])
            sigma = float(number_seqnuber.split(',')[3])
            if number > mu:
                deviation = number - mu
            else:
                deviation = mu - number

            if deviation > sigma * 2:
                logger_ws_client.info("Time - {}, number - {}, sequence_number - {}".format(datetime.today(),
                                                                                            number,
                                                                                            sequence_number))
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            # print(dir((channel_layer)))
            await channel_layer.send("deviation_message", {
                "type": "chat.message",
                "text": "Hello there!",
            })


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(recv_hand_message())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**consumer.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer


class MessageConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("deviation_message", self.channel_name)
        print('channel_name______{}'.format(self.channel_name))
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("deviation_message", self.channel_name)
        pass

    def websocket_receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "deviation_message",
            {
                "type": "deviation_message",
                "text": text_data,
            },
        )

    def deviation_message(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=event["text"])
```

**HTML-страница**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Message notifier</title>
    <script></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Message notifier
        <textarea id="message" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea><br/>
    </h1>
    <script>
        var messageSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/djch' + '/');
        messageSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            var message = data['message'];
            document.querySelector('#message').value = message;
        };

        messageSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Запуск приложения:

1. python manage.py runserver
2. python ws_server.py
3. python ws_client.py
   Когда доходит до исполнения строчки

   await channel_layer.send("deviation_message", {
                   "type": "chat.message",
                   "text": "Hello there!",
               })

Получаю ошибку *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'*

Весь трейсбек

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ws_client.py", line 43, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(recv_hand_message())
  File "c:\python37-32\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "ws_client.py", line 37, in recv_hand_message
    await channel_layer.send("deviation_message", {
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Помогите понять почему получаю None, при условии, что конфиг для channel_layers есть и в consumer я регистрирую группу. Возможно ли, что `settings.configure(DEBUG=True)` не дает мне полного доступа к settings.py и по этому channel_layers пустой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел, как можно исправить код, что бы не получать **None** при вызове `channel_layer = get_channel_layer()`. Может кому пригодится. Нужно локально в файле ws_client.py  сконфигурировать CHANNEL_LAYERS. Вот такой строчкой `settings.configure(CHANNEL_LAYERS=CHANNEL_LAYERS)` И теперь get_channel_layer() возвращает не **None**